# How to show divs on browser scroll

Tags: javascript, browser, scroll, html, lazy-loading

My page layout has several group of divs repeating like

```
<div--1>

  <div--2>

    <div--3>

       <div--4>
```

Tthis structure repeats over several times.  I would like to hide the contents of div--4 to be hidden untill the user scrolls to that element.  How can we achieve that functionality?

I found a plugin that works with images like that(http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload)

Answer (score 2):

This code will show and hide the divs based on the mouse position.  Not sure how to detect a particular div is on the screen currently or not.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Show/Hide Divs</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function showMyContents(control)
{
 control.children["myContents"].style.display = 'inline';
}

function hideMyContents(control)
{
 control.children["myContents"].style.display = 'none';
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div onmouseover="showMyContents(this);" onmouseout="hideMyContents(this);">show 1
 <div style="display:none" id="myContents">My Contents1</div>
</div>
<div onmouseover="showMyContents(this);" onmouseout="hideMyContents(this);">show 2
 <div style="display:none" id="myContents">My Contents2</div>
</div>
<div onmouseover="showMyContents(this);" onmouseout="hideMyContents(this);">show 3
 <div style="display:none" id="myContents">My Contents3</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks chris for the code !! can anybody help me with show divs on browser scroll. initailly when the page loads only the divs (div4) on the visible portion of page sholud be shown. inorder for the page to load faster